# Hide backup drive from guest user

Tags: time-machine, macos, external-disk, guest-account

I have a backup drive connected to my mac mini, which I just upgraded to yosemite. I created a guest account, and unfortunately, the guest can browse the backup drive. Is there an easy way to prevent that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use TimeMachine you can encrypt the backup. Go to system preferences, (re-)select the drive and tick the checkbox for encryption.
As for the external drive as a whole, you could only apply certain permissions to folders using the information screen (right click the specific folder) or use a drive that supports password protection.